# Tool to display html as a hierarchy

Tags: html

I am working on a crawler and as a result, I need to look at the HTML of the site I will crawl, to make assumptions (Which will be soft coded).

HTML of large sites is not easy to read. Is there a tool which can display the HTML in some sort of tree-like hierarchy?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how *you* can look at it in a tree hierarchy or the *crawler*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking forward to see the "tree-like hierarchy", you have this tool : http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

Comment: Good link but it can't parse the html I provide it (from a live site, not made by me).

Comment: If you just want to parse, why do you need the "tree-like hierarchy"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actually look (like, you know, with your eyes) at some HTML source in a nicely formatted tree, then use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). The HTML tab of that is perfect (and even editable if you want to play with it).

Comment: Firebug is highly recommended, but be careful. Firebug display the HTML as Firefox reads it, which means it can manipulate it from the original context (the original HTML used). For example, it can close tags where they weren't closed in the original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned IE8.

Tools -> Developer Tools.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone here is using IE8

Comment: Considering IE still dominates the browser usage share, you should probably consider using IE for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has something pretty similar to Firebug, built in. Right-click anywhere in the page and click *Inspect element.* That gives you a fully collapsed tree view of the source. You can expand and drill down as necessary.